# Docker storage on host machine

Tags: docker, storage

During build steps of a docker image, I get errors on insufficient storage space. I've limited space on `/` but recently managed to mount a new storage device on `/data`. So how can I force docker daemon to use that directory to store underlying container and images data? or even move existing images and containers to there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by by modifying systemd's docker start up script. Open file `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` with your favorite text editor and replace the following line where `/data/path/docker` is a location of your new chosen docker directory:

```
FROM: 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// 
TO:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -g /data/path/docker -H fd://
```

When ready stop docker service:

```
systemctl stop docker
```